# how to set default ant path in mac os x?

Tags: macos, ant, bash

I have two installations of ant. (1.7 and 1.9). I want to change my ant path to use latest version (1.7)

Here is what I tried:
In `.bash_profile`, I added

```
 export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.4
    export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin

source ~/.bash_profile

echo $ANT_HOME
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.4
```

So far it looks good. but when I tried

```
which ant
/usr/local/apache-ant-1.7.0/bin/ant
```

This points to older version of ant. how do I change this to point to newer version.

Here is what i have in `/usr/local`

```
ls /usr/local/
apache-ant-1.7.0/            bin/                         maven-3.0.5/                 mysql-5.5.40-osx10.6-x86_64/ subl
apache-ant-1.9.4/            etc/                         mysql/                       share/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PATH` variable may be pointing to the 1.7 version already. Try including `ANT_HOME` *first* to take order precedence:

```
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

You can print the `PATH` variable in all cases to see the current order if any.